# How to get all Customers records in Northwind (with and without orders)

Tags: sql-server-2005, record, orders, northwind

With this code I will get only customers records with total of orders more than zero, but I need get the customers with zero total of orders also.

How to get all Customers record in `Northwind` with and without orders?

[image: how to get all Customers record in Northwind with and without orders]

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN will return customers who do not have orders.

```
SELECT      Customers.CustomerID,
            Customers.CompanyName,
            COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Total

FROM        Customers
LEFT JOIN   Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY    Customers.CustomerID,
            Customers.CompanyName
```

This query returns all customers (91 in the Northwind DB) and the total displays 0 for those who do not have orders.

Is this what you were after?

Comment: Thanks Noobie3001

Comment: be sure to accept the answer @MohammadAlobaili if it was correct and solved your issue